# How do I invoke a function in the main file from a method in a class file?

Tags: javascript

My project has two files. An html file, and a javascript file. In the java script file I am trying to end it by sending the name of the object to my WritingOnScreen function in the html file. Everything i've tried so far just prints as undefined.
This is the js file.

```
class Vehicle {
    constructor(name){
        this.lowestspeed=20;
        this.highestspeed=100;
        this.speed=(this.lowestspeed+(Math.random()*this.highestspeed));
        this.name=name;
    }
}
class Car extends Vehicle {
    constructor(logoY,wheelY,r,g,b){
        super();
        this.logoX=20;
        //this.logoY=logoY;
        this.lwheelX=10;
        this.rwheelX=40;
        this.wheelY=wheelY;
        this.bodyX=20;
        this.r=r;
        this.g=g;
        this.b=b;
        
    }
    Rectangle(x,y,w,h,color){
        ctx.fillStyle=color;
        ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
    }
    Arc(x,y,radius,Sangle,Eangle,color,style,CounterCW){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y,radius,Sangle,Eangle,CounterCW); //Starting angle and Ending Angle, counter clockwise
        if(style=='fill'){
            ctx.fillStyle=color;
            ctx.fill();
        }
        else if(style=='stroke'){
            ctx.strokeStyle=color;
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
    render(){
        this.Arc(this.lwheelX,this.wheelY,10,1*Math.PI,4*Math.PI,'rgb(0,0,0)','stroke',false);
        this.Arc(this.rwheelX,this.wheelY,10,1*Math.PI,4*Math.PI,'rgb(0,0,0)','stroke',false);
        this.Arc((this.rwheelX-15),(this.wheelY-15),20,1*Math.PI,4*Math.PI,'rgb('+this.r+','+this.g+','+this.b+')','fill',false);
    }
    update(){
        this.render();
        if(this.rwheelX+20<canvas.width)
        {
            this.lwheelX+=this.speed;
            this.rwheelX+=this.speed;
            //this.logoX+=this.speed;
            this.bodyX+=this.speed;
        }
        else{
            return stop(this.name); 
        }
    }
    
}
```

And this is where it's meant to go other file. (This part is also in javascript but having two files is part of the assignment)

```
function stop(winner){
                clearInterval(animate1);
                clearInterval(animate2);
                clearInterval(animate3);
                clearInterval(background);
                ClearScene();
                WritingOnScreen("You win "+winner+"!!!");
                
            }
            function WritingOnScreen(writing){
                ctx.font= "50px ariel";
                var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,640,500);
                gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgb(255,0,128)");
                gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgb(105,297,240)");
                ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
                ctx.fillText(writing,150,200);
```

I have a different call to the Writing on screen function in this file which works fine so I know it has something to do with it being between two files.

Comment: You'll have to give us quite a bit more code before we can tell exactly what's wrong and how to fix - but it's almost certainly because `this` doesn't refer to the object you expect it to. It fundamentally depends on what function that `else` block is inside, and how that function is called - neither of which you show us.

Comment: Oh, I see. I've just updated it to show the whole file.

Comment: Thanks - it looks like the root cause is simpler than I thought. The `this.name` will surely always be `undefined` because you don't pass any `name` to the `Vehicle` class in the `super` call in `Car`'s constructor. (I also note in passing, although I don't think it's relevant here but surely is somewhere in your code, that in `Vehicle`'s constructor, you use `this.lowestspeed` and `this.highestspeed` but never set either of these properties.)